# Values assigned to incorrect node when converting xml to data frame

Tags: r, xml, list, nested-lists

I have tens of thousands of XML files that I am trying to convert into R data frames. Each XML file may have different nodes, different values at each node, different structure, etc. so I am trying to do this in a way that doesn't require explicitly typing out the structure of each individual file. However, I am having trouble assigning values to the correct tags.

Suppose I have the below XML contained in a file named "dat.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HH_V2 id="HH_V2">
    <start>2017-01-30T11:31:56.811Z</start>
    <end>2017-01-30T12:08:19.489Z</end>
    <today>2017-01-30</today>
    <deviceid>351569060022943</deviceid>
    <time_st>2017-01-30</time_st>
    <int_name>21</int_name>
    <superv>4</superv>
    <region>2</region>
    <new_ea_flag>0</new_ea_flag>
    <unique_id>c3d5c37d-b5c6-4b9d-a922-3b4f5be0e5ac</unique_id>
    <village>Boana</village>
    <hh_serial>71710003101</hh_serial>
    <hh_serial2>71710003101</hh_serial2>
    <id_consent>
        <iconsent>
            <iconsentlong />
        </iconsent>
        <consent>1</consent>
    </id_consent>
        <meta>
        <instanceID>uuid:ff93ead6-77b3-4c14-be7c-cbeb520ce0d7</instanceID>
    </meta>
</HH_V2>
```

Using the xml file above and the script below, my dataframe contains a column named "meta" with the value uuid:ff93ead6-77b3-4c14-be7c-cbeb520ce0d7. However, I was expecting/hoping for it to contain a column instead named "instanceID" with that same value based on the fact that the latter tag immediately surrounds the value. This happens in general for other nested nodes. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(XML)

# Convert xml file to list of lists
temp_list <- "dat.xml" %>% XML::xmlParse() %>% XML::xmlToList()

# Unlist and store content as a single column with row
# names for each variable in that node and the value of
#  the variable in a single column.
for (j in 1:length(temp_list)) {
  temp_list[[j]] <- temp_list[[j]] %>% unlist(recursive = TRUE) %>% 
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }

# Each file is now a list of data frames comprised of 
# 1 column of values and row names for each variable. So
# we bind these in order of their appearance in the list
# of data frames
temp_list <- do.call(rbind, temp_list)

# Since we want each row to be a column and each column
# to be a variable ('wide' format), we transpose the
# dataframe to produce a single row for each instance
# of the submitted form
t(temp_list) %>% as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Would `as.data.frame(as.list(unlist(temp_list, recursive = TRUE)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` (on your unmodified `temp_list`) do it? Minor inconveniences: everything is converted to character, and names are prefixed with parent node name, for instance `"meta.instanceID "` where you wanted `"instanceID"`

Comment: Works on toy data set, testing it later on full data. Care to explain why this works in comparison to my code? Inconveniences are fine (no petiods '.' in colnames and can keep substring w/ child.

Answer (score 0):

After `temp_list <- "dat.xml" %>% XML::xmlParse() %>% XML::xmlToList()` I suggest the simpler code:

```
as.data.frame(as.list(unlist(temp_list, recursive = TRUE)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#                      start                      end      today        deviceid    time_st int_name superv region new_ea_flag                            unique_id village   hh_serial  hh_serial2 id_consent.consent                           meta.instanceID .attrs.id
# 1 2017-01-30T11:31:56.811Z 2017-01-30T12:08:19.489Z 2017-01-30 351569060022943 2017-01-30       21      4      2           0 c3d5c37d-b5c6-4b9d-a922-3b4f5be0e5ac   Boana 71710003101 71710003101                  1 uuid:ff93ead6-77b3-4c14-be7c-cbeb520ce0d7     HH_V2
```

`unlist` with `recursive = TRUE` flattens the whole list to a vector (a character vector with implicit conversion of numerics *(edit: just noticed that everything was already character anyway, `xmlParse` did not do any automatic class attribution)*, so be careful to convert back if you need those as `integer` or `double`). The default `use.names = TRUE` concatenates names in nested list with a dot, giving you names such as `id_consent.consent` and `meta.instanceID`.

Then `as.data.frame(as.list())` makes it a one row data frame.

The difference with your code is: the for loop replaces each parent node with a single dataframe of 1 observation x 1 variable, with no rownames, hence losing nested names, keeping only the most "outer" names of parent nodes. Then `rbind` piles them together, and those names serve as rownames in the resulting dataframe. `t()` converts it back to a character matrix! (with the names now used as colnames). Finally, `as.data.frame` turns it back again into a data frame. This is a lot of unnecessary steps. My solution also maybe has some (`unlist()` then `as.list()` ;-) ... but slightly less ;-)